# Manipulating http responses using bridge

Tags: wifi, httpresponse, fiddler, wireshark, bridge

I'm thinking about my next project, and i was wondering about something.

is it possible manipulating httpResponses body, transported by a local bridge? can it be handled using fiddler / wireshark, and only then to be sent to the original destination?

any idea / suggestions will be grate!

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is explicitly designed to enable altering HTTP requests and responses, either manually using breakpoints and inspectors, or automatically using the scripting engine or extensions. This blog post goes into more details: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-20/breakpoints-in-fiddler

It's not entirely clear what you mean when you say: "transported by a local bridge." Fiddler, as a proxy, views and manipulates traffic sent to it. There are other tools that can modify traffic in a *transparent* manner (e.g. the code can manipulate raw TCP/IP without the client knowing that the code is there) but these tend to be quite a bit more difficult to use.